# Display value from DB when tab an input field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a form with several input fields.
when input field base and lot are filled in, I want to run a query to put some extra data to my form without submit the form.

```
<tbody>
    <form action='' method='post'> 
        <td></td>
        <td>                
                DATA HERE!
        </td>
        <td><input type='number' name='base' class='form-control' value=''></td>
        <td><input type='number' name='lot' class='form-control' value=''></td>
        <td><input type='number' name='split' class='form-control' value=''></td>
        <td><input type='number' name='sub' class='form-control' value=''></td>
        <td><input type='number' name='seq' class='form-control' value=''></td>
        <td><input type='number' name='indirect' class='form-control' value=''></td>
        <td><input type='number' name='datum' class='form-control' value=''></td>
        <td><input type='number' name='clockin' class='form-control' value=''></td>
        <td><input type='number' name='clockout' class='form-control' value=''></td>
        <td><input type='number' name='break' class='form-control' value=''></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type='number' name='multiplier' class='form-control' value=''></td>
        <td><button class='btn btn-default' type='submit' name='update'>Update</button></td>
        <td><button class='btn btn-default' type='submit' name='verwijderen'>Verwijderen</button></td>
    </form>
</tbody>
```

The value has to come from:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM LABOR_TICKET WHERE WORKEDORDER_BASE_ID = '".$base."' AND WORKORDER_LOT_ID = '".$lot."'";
```

I have really no idea how to do it.

Normally I can find something about it, but I dont know how to formulate it right ha ha

Comment: can't you put trough javascript an onchange function on both base and lot to run an Ajax call to another php page to do the query you need?

Comment: If you want to do it without submitting the form, then you need to replace the HTTP request that submitting the form would generate with a HTTP request generated using JavaScript and AJAX